# How do I decrement the length of an inputed string?

Tags: python, recursion, counter

I defined a recursive function that returns the number of digits:

```
def counter(z, c = 0):

    z = len(z)
    if z == 0:
        return c
    else:
        return counter(z - 1,c + 1)
```

I understand that on the second call, the function will assign the length of integer 3 to z.How do I assign the previous string minus one character so that my functions counts every character?

Comment: Strings are indexed like arrays or lists. E.g. `z[:-1]` would mean all characters except the last one.

Comment: Probably `if not z: return c` as your condition and `return counter(z[1:], c+ 1)` as your recursion... (untested though)... isn't it a bit odd though calling `len` for every single character?

Comment: Is `z` an int? You can't call `len` on an int. (If `z` is something you *can* call `len` on, then it seems strange to use `len` in a function that's supposed to compute the length of its input recursively.)

Comment: @user2357112 yeah... I get the feeling `z` should be the string and `if not z` should be the return condition and `z[1:]` in the recursive call - doesn't seem right to use `len` here...

Comment: @JonClements where else would I assign the length of z to itself?

Comment: If `z` is an `int` and you need its length, just use `len(str(z))`. If z is something else you can call `len` on, just do so. What is the point of that function?

Comment: @MisterTusk that's what you're incrementing `c` for... if you were supposed to use `len` then you'd just use `len` once and avoid the whole unnecessary recursion... see my comment above and Adam's answer which I think is what you're supposed to be doing and understanding here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do `z=len(z)`, because you need the original `z` to pass to the recursive call. Instead, do `zl=len(z)`, change your `if` to `zl==0`, and make your final line `return counter(z[1:], c+1)`. Square brackets with a colon are a slice operator; `"abc"[1:]=="bc"`.

...btw, *technically* you don't even need to get the `len()` of `z`, since python treats empty lists as falsy in if-expressions. So your code could just be:

```
def counter(z, c=0):
    if not z: return c
    return counter(z[1:], c+1)
```

Comment: Could you show me how to do the exact same thing but for a number please?

Answer (score 0):

You only have to pass the length of z in the first call to function.

```
def counter(z, c = 0):
if z == 0:
    return c
else:
    return counter(z - 1,c + 1)

# Main call
z = len(z)
result = counter(z)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to slice the string. For example use `z[:-1]`. This will return all the characters minus the last one. Alternatively you can just count them with `len(z)`.  Also setting `z=len(z)` will not work because you loose the string.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution: pass a string and no counter value, than slice in your recursive call the string without one character and terminate when string is empty:

```
def counter(s, c=0):
    if not s:
        return c
    else:
        return counter(s[:-1], c+1)

c = counter("abc")
```